# How to write a functional test for Symfony2 email sent with SwitfMailer

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer

I want to write a functional test (WebTestCase) for a Symfony2 project, for a controller that sends an email to a user.

I want to test whether SwiftMailer has successfully sent/spooled the email, or in other words if the ->send() function returned successfully.  I also need to assert the body contents, email address and check if the content type is text/html for the mail sent.

How do I go about doing this?